# Efficient Way to Find Indices of Unique Rows in PyTorch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am working in PyTorch and I trying to find the index of the first occurrence of each unique row. Here's what I have so far:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

# Example tensor
data = torch.rand(100, 5)
data[np.random.choice(100, 50, replace=False)] = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

# Finding unique rows
u_data, inverse_indices, counts = torch.unique(data, dim=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

# Finding the first occurrence index of each unique row
unique_indices = torch.zeros(len(u_data), dtype=torch.long)
for idx in range(len(u_data)):
    unique_indices[idx] = torch.where(inverse_indices == idx)[0][0]
```

This code works but has an inefficient "unique_indices" loop. Is there a more efficient, Pytorch-like way to obtain unique_indices?

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid a loop is to use a 2D tensor. I'm going to use the value '1000' as a placeholder for any value that is larger than the amount of rows in the original data tensor, i.e. `1000 > 100`.

So, I'll create a 2D tensor `A` whose dimensions are the number of original rows by the number of unique rows. I'll initialize it to `1000`, which means "undefined row index". Then, for each original row index `i`, I'll set `A[i] = inverse_indices[i]`. Once finished, the `ith` row of `A` will be mostly `1000`, except for the columns whose indices are the indices of the unique rows where row `i` is now located.

Now, let's consider this tensor `A` column wise. The `jth` column is the `jth` unique row. Its values are again mostly `1000`, except for some rows that will contain `j`. The `argmin` of the column is exactly the index of the first original row that mapped to unique row `j`.

Here's the code, based on your own code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

# Example tensor
data = torch.rand(100, 5)
data[np.random.choice(100, 50, replace=False)] = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

# Finding unique rows
u_data, inverse_indices, counts = torch.unique(data, dim=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

# Finding the first occurrence index of each unique row
unique_indices = torch.zeros(len(u_data), dtype=torch.long)
for idx in range(len(u_data)):
    unique_indices[idx] = torch.where(inverse_indices == idx)[0][0]

# My suggestion:

A = 1000 * torch.ones((len(data), len(u_data)), dtype=torch.long)
A[torch.arange(len(data)), inverse_indices] = inverse_indices
unique_indices2 = torch.argmin(A, dim=0)

# Verify my method matches yours
print(torch.allclose(unique_indices2,unique_indices))
```

A note regarding efficiency: My code removes the loop and does not use the `where` function, but it uses a lot more memory. Whether it's more efficient for your actual use case depends on how fast `argmin` is on your hardware, on the dimensions of the actual problem and on how much you value memory